# Wix 3.7 Installcondition not work

Tags: wix, wix3.7

I'm trying to build 1 installer that in run time will decide which msi to run x64 or x86 the relevant part of the code is:

```
<Chain>
  <ExePackage
  Id='PreInst'
  Vital='no'
  Name='bsutil.exe'
  SourceFile='$(var.BASourceDir)\bsutil.exe'
  SuppressSignatureVerification='no'
  InstallCommand='-install -sequence PreInstall -config [BSUtilConfigPath]'
  UninstallCommand='-uninstall -sequence PreInstall -config [BSUtilConfigPath]'
  RepairCommand='-repair -sequence PreInstall -config [BSUtilConfigPath]'
  DetectCondition='WixBundleInstalled'
  InstallSize='10'
  PerMachine='yes'
  Compressed='yes'
    >
    <Payload
      Id='bsutil_Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll'
      SourceFile='$(var.BASourceDir)\Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll'
      Compressed='yes'/>
    <Payload
      Id='PreInstBSUtil'
      Name='bsutil.exe.config'
      SourceFile='$(var.BASourceDir)\bsutil.exe.config'
      Compressed='yes'
      />
  </ExePackage>

  <MsiPackage
Id='WiGigStack_x86'
Vital='yes'
Name='Win32\Install\Data\WiGigInstaller_x86.msi'
SourceFile='$(var.WiGigPackageSourceDir)\WiGigInstaller_x86.msi'
SuppressSignatureVerification='yes'
Cache='yes'
InstallCondition='NOT VersionNT64'
ForcePerMachine='yes'
CacheId='{804C8E4E-A874-4A48-B0CE-2E34D614D894}v$(var.ProductVersion)'
    >
    <MsiProperty Name='INSTALLDIR' Value='[MWGRootInstallPath]' />
    <MsiProperty Name='ICHAIN' Value='1' />
    <MsiProperty Name='FCODE' Value='1' />
    <MsiProperty Name='WIXMSIPROP' Value='[WixMsiProperties_Driver]' />
  </MsiPackage>


  <MsiPackage

  Id='WiGigStack_x64'
  Vital='yes'
  Name='Win64\Install\Data\WiGigInstaller_x64.msi'
  SourceFile='$(var.WiGigPackageSourceDir)\WiGigInstaller_x64.msi'
  SuppressSignatureVerification='yes'
  Cache='yes'
  ForcePerMachine='yes'
  InstallCondition='VersionNT64'
  CacheId='{804C8E4E-A874-4A48-B0CE-2E34D614D894}v$(var.ProductVersion)'
    >
    <MsiProperty Name='INSTALLDIR' Value='[MWGRootInstallPath]' />
    <MsiProperty Name='ICHAIN' Value='1' />
    <MsiProperty Name='FCODE' Value='1' />
    <MsiProperty Name='WIXMSIPROP' Value='[WixMsiProperties_Driver]' />
  </MsiPackage>

  <ExePackage
   Id='PostInst'
   Vital='no'
   Name='bsutil.exe'
   SourceFile='$(var.BASourceDir)\bsutil.exe'
   SuppressSignatureVerification='no'
   InstallCommand='-install -sequence PostInstall -config [BSUtilConfigPath]'
   UninstallCommand='-uninstall -sequence PostInstall -config [BSUtilConfigPath]'
   RepairCommand='-repair -sequence PostInstall -config [BSUtilConfigPath]'
   DetectCondition='WixBundleInstalled'
   InstallSize='10'
   PerMachine='yes'
   Compressed='yes'
    >
    <Payload
      Id='PostInstBSUtil'
      Name='bsutil.exe.config'
      SourceFile='$(var.BASourceDir)\bsutil.exe.config'
      Compressed='yes'
      />
  </ExePackage>
</Chain>
```

But when I run the installer on x64 machine he try also to execute x86 msi and failed. In the log I can see that he evaluate the condition(x64 or x86) right, but still insist to install both msi.

What I'm doing wrong?